# Webrtc Load Testing - Seeking Expert Advice

Tags: webrtc, load-testing, web-testing

I've been tasked with conducting load testing for a webrtc service, specifically focusing on audio/video calls and conference capacity. The testing environment is a web version, and after analyzing traffic using Wireshark during a 1-on-1 call, I observed the use of STUN protocols. This prompted the decision to concentrate on webrtc (Maybe I'm wrong). I have studied the basic principles, but I am seeking advice on simulating load and analyzing results.

I attempted to understand the intricacies of webrtc load testing, expecting to find effective methods for simulating user load in conference scenarios. However, I haven't found anything specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service should have an [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API) so you could use a load testing tool which supports the programming language in which your service is written and simulate the client actions via it.

If web version is the only way for communicating with the backend you can consider some ["black-box"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing) load testing tools like:

- [WebRTC Perf](https://github.com/vpalmisano/webrtcperf#webrtc-perf)
- Apache JMeter with [WebSocket Samplers plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers) and/or [GStreamer bindings for Java](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/bindings/java.html)
- [testRTC](https://testrtc.com/webrtc-testing-made-easy/)